# Route wlan0 to openVPN tunnel and rest to eth0

Tags: networking, iptables, openvpn

I'm having problems to create route/iptables rules for following configuration:

1. I have an openVPN server (tun type) running on my raspberry machine at home
2. At work i have company pc (behind proxy) that creates tunnel using openVPN to my home machine
3. At work i have USB Wifi dongle (wlan0) connected to my company pc that should provide internet using the tunnel to machine at my home

Now i need to create rules for:
1. All traffic going via wlan0 to route to tunnel 
2. Rest of the traffic route to eth0 - company network behind proxy

Default route rule at company pc (linuxmint 15) for all traffic going via eth0 - proxy:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
default 10.131.4.1 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 eth0
```

--> that rule must stay on eth0

Comment: Hello do you mind providing us a bit more info like the os you're using at work ? the list of your network interface ? and the IPs of your computer ?

Comment: At work: linuxmint 15

eth0 : 10.131.4.74
wlan0: 172.16.1.1
tun0:  10.8.0.14

At home: raspbian running on raspberrypi
tun0: 10.8.0.1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send traffic that comes in from wlan0 down tun0, but traffic that originates locally to go to eth0, the easiest way is to just use a separate routing table:

```
# enable IP forwarding
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward 1

# Add a "default rule" to a non-default routing table
ip route add default dev tun0 table 10

# Specify that this table is to be used for anything from the wlan interface
ip rule add iif wlan0 table 10
```

... and that should be it, really. This assumes you do not need NAT; if you control both the VPN server and the wlan IP address range, that should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

So admitting that all private ip addresses will be routed to your work network, I would do something like this.

```
route add default gw tun0
route add 10.0.0.0/8 gw eth0
route add 172.16.0.0/12 gw eth0
route add 192.168.0.0/16  gw eth0
```

I do not have a linux to test this configuration but that's what it should look like I think. There's probably error in the exact synthax. but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your tun OpenVpn server configuration. Basicly, it handles only (!) networks, defined by server side.
So, you configuration for wlan0 (let's say, 192.168.0.0/24) users via tun0 will be done as follows:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s wlan0 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -A FORWARD -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

This marks all packets, coming from wlan0 and sets tun0 address as source address, and of course - allows forwarding. Of course, ip forwarding must me enabled in sysctl.
Add routing table to `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` - for instance, `100 wlantun`

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 table wlantun
ip rule add default via ${tun gw} dev tun0 table wlantun
```

This will route all market packets to tun0. However, I suggest to use `tap` instead of `tun` tunnel to achieve the result.