# How do I forward all packets from wlan0 to tun0 (OpenVPN)?

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn

I have wlan0 and eth0. Eth0 is connected to the internet and wlan0 is an access point. I connected to an OpenVPN server with the "--pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway" option so that it doesn't automatically route ALL traffic through the VPN which is not what I want to do.

I'm trying to route all traffic from wlan0 (access point) to tun0. That way any clients connected to my access point will be using the VPN. I tried doing this using iptables:

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

This doesn't work (and the counters don't update either). I tried replacing tun0 with eth0 which DID work (but ofc completely bypassing the VPN), so I'm assuming that the problem lies with tun0. I also read somewhere that IP routing tables are better suited for this. If that's true, how can I do this?

Comment: This is a routing issue basically. You might be interested in **policy routing**. Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104066/190343) help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your wlan subnet is 192.168.1.0/24 and tun0 IP is 10.10.10.99:

Execute the following commands on the VPN gateway

Enable routing, if not yet enabled:

```
sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Delete the first two NAT rules that you already have, while preserving the FORWARD rules:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -L -n --line-numbers
sudo iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING 1
```

Once the NAT rules are removed, add back a single NAT rule in right format.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 ! -d 192.168.1.0/24 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Last step is to deal with the route table by using "Policy Routing":

```
sudo ip rule add from 192.168.1.0/24 table 99
sudo ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 via 10.10.10.99 dev tun0 table 99
```

Reference [here](http://wiki.wlug.org.nz/SourceBasedRouting) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/376667/how-to-route-only-specific-subnet-source-ip-to-a-particular-interface)

Comment: Is there a reason my way (with iptables) works for eth0 but not for tun0?

Comment: Okay so I didn't have to remove any of my NAT rules, but it works now! Is there a way for me to add the routes given that the IP is dynamic?

Comment: The source IP is dynamic? Then it means your wlan IP is dynamic. I most cases, wlan IP range is static, although hosts can get dynamic IPs. In the route statement, we did not specify a single IP, but a range (192.168.1.0/24 for example). As long you have the correct IP range, you can have the route table covered at all times. If the tun0 IP is dynamic, you can create a simple script that will monitor the IP address and save into a variable. That variable will then be called in the route statement